# How to import/export font styles from TextEdit?

Tags: macos, font, formatting

I've got some custom font styles that were created on another Mac which I'd like to export and import to another Mac, I don't see any obvious way of doing this — is it possible?

[image]

**EDIT**: Since there is some confusion as to what a custom font style is, the animation should show clearly what I'm referring to. So for example I would like to export/import the style "Highlight".

Comment: @TomGewecke: Any app that uses standard fonts and allows styles to be set... TextEdit is a prime example.

Comment: @TomGewecke: I've updated the question to show more clearly what I'm referring to. When I transfer a document to another machine the favorite style is not available in the list, although the document does have the correct formatting. This would essentially mean I would have to create all of the custom styles again, which would be an arduous task.

Comment: Are the two computers synched via iCloud?  I think styles should sync

Comment: @TomGewecke: No, they are two completely unrelated computers.

Comment: Can you transfer a doc with samples of all the styles, then  just save each one to favorites on the second computer?  You just have to fill in the name again but not recreate all the details I think.

Comment: @TomGewecke: That’s what I’m dreading, since I have hundreds of styles...

Comment: They should be in a .plist somewhere, but no idea which one